# irBeams inside IRSensor

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with gazebo simulator, in the IRSensor.hh file (in gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/ir/IRSensor.hh) is declared

```
private std::vector<RaySensor*> irBeams;
```

And then, in the IRSensor.cc file (in gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/ir/IRSensor.cc) is used this structure in order to use the parameters of the sensor like

```
    unsigned int IRSensor::GetIRCount() const
    {
      return this->irBeams.size();
    }
```

But this structure is nowhere defined or filled inside this file. How is this possible? Where is it?

I ask because i try to use this function (GetIRCount) after configuring a IRSensor through a XML file  and it always return 0 because it is empty and i really don't why.

https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/browser/server/sensors/ir/IRSensor.cc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11284/irbeams-inside-irsensor/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I wrote [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2239/gazebo-irsensor-parameters-configuration-xml), this seems to be a bug in Gazebo. The relevant ticket is https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/30.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0